# String contains () in Java returns false even if string is present

Tags: java, string, contains

I am currently learning programming in Java and was practicing the String contains(), which is used to check whether a particular string within a string exists or not. But in the given code, the contains() returns false even if the string is present.

```
import java.util.*;
class StringPractice1{
public static void main(String arg[]){
    System.out.println("Enter a string:- ");
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = sc1.next();
    System.out.println("Enter the string you want to find:- ");
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s2 = sc2.next();
    if(s1.contains(s2)){
        System.out.println("It contains the string '"+s2+"'.");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No such string exists.");
    }
}}
```

[Output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skazr.jpg)

Comment: `next()` on a `Scanner` returns just one word, not the whole line.  Also, don't use a new `Scanner` for every input.  The behavior might not be what you expect.

Comment: My guess is that there is something going on with line separators from the scanner inputs.

Comment: add the following after the `else` block and you'll see what happens: `System.out.printf("s1:"+s1+"; s2:"+s2+";");`

Comment: @ajb I think you are right, it is the problem with next() as it returns true for the starting word of the sentence. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s1 = sc1.next();
```

will only take one word i.e. `I` in your case because of the occurrence of a space.

However if you use `sc1.nextLine();`, the whole sentence will be taken, i.e. "I am a boy". Thereby solving your problem.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for.